# Getting different results in python while using “ (U+201C) instead of " (Quotation mark typed from keyboard) in replace()

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, utf-8

I was trying to count the number of words in a text file using python.
To remove punctuations I used:

```
word = word.replace("“","")
```

My code gave different result when I used:

```
word = word.replace("\"","")
```

Previously, I was having some encoding related problems while opening the text file, the statement I used was:

```
file = open('98-0.txt')
```

Error code:

```
'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 6552: character maps to <undefined>
```

So I used the following statement:

```
file = open('98-0.txt',encoding="utf-8-sig")
```

I am using Anaconda 1.6.5, python 3.6.3 on Windows 8.

Comment: ??? Yes, when you do different things you get different results. What's the question?

Comment: The quotation mark you type at the keyboard is U+0022. U+201C is a Unicode Left Double Quotation Mark which is a completely different character. Look closely at `word = word.replace("“","")` and you will see the difference.

Comment: [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark#Unicode_code_point_table) are all the codepoint variants of quotation marks that you'll find. Make sure you account for all the ones that you're processing.

Comment: @Aran-Fey I was given a .txt file and I had to count the occurrence of every unique word. So, I was opening the .txt file and using the lower() and strip() method to store the tokenized words in a list and then I was checking if the word is present in stopwords list (contained all the words to ignore) and the storing it in a dict along with the occurrence. Meanwhile I was also replacing the punctuations (, . / "). Replacing the " with “ gave me a different word count. Do you want to see the exact output?

Comment: @droooze Okay thanks!

Comment: "Why am I getting different results when I use the U+201C character for replacement instead of the standard quotation U+0022? Does it have something to do with the fact that my encoding is utf-8-sig?" See, it isn't that hard to articulate your problem, is it?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ No, it isn't now. Thanks for your comment.